# Cordova app with integrated plugin on webview crash when try to exit plugin webview (android test)

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, crash, cordova-plugins

I have a problem when i try to go back from a cordova plugin integrated on cordova. When i try to do it, the app crashes, I debugged first the javascript and then the native code that javascript call and this is the instruction that make app crash.

**cordova.getActivity().finish();**

This is in **TestPlugin.java** file in this most global context:

```
   if (action.equals("open")) {

    try {
      cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity(),
            PhemiumEnduserActivity.class);
          cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
          cordova.getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
      });
      callback.success("");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      callback.error(e.getMessage());
    }

  }
  else if( action.equals("exit_app") ) {
    try {
      cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          cordova.getActivity().finish();
        }
      });
      callback.success("");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      callback.error(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

When the app calls the plugin executes the "open" part and when i click the back button makes the "exit_app" part and then on **cordova.getActivity().finish();** app crashes with no error on the android studio console. There is no signal of webview close. What i'm doing wrong? Why it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post full plugin code or repository, but i think is because you try to finish activity in another thread, or activity no more exist (getActivity return null).

You need to try with somewhat like this:

```
protected Activity mActivity;
....
else if( action.equals("exit_app") ) {
    mActivity = cordova.getActivity();
    try {
      cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         if(mActivity!=null)
           mActivity.finish();
        }
      });
      callback.success("");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      callback.error(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

For more trace info try to open android project in Android studio and debug it.